# Image is not being found? Unable to display image

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have this snip in two different projects, and for some reason its not working on my current project:

```
  Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, right: 80),
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
            ),
```

Here is the structure of the files

[image: tree]

The error below says the asset is not found?

I also tried to move the image into the same file but it didnt work

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/images/logo.png.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.loadBuffer
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.loadBuffer
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure>
#4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent
#5      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey
#6      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey
#7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>
#8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>
#9      SynchronousFuture.then
#10     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey
#11     ImageProvider.resolve
#12     _ImageState._resolveImage
#13     _ImageState.reassemble
#14     StatefulElement.reassemble
#15     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure>
#16     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren
#17     Element.reassemble
#18     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure>
#19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren
#20     Element.reassemble
#21     Element.reassemble.<anonymous closure>
#22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren
....
....
...
#595    BindingBase.registerSignalServiceExtension.<anonymous closure>
#596    BindingBase.registerServiceExtension.<anonymous closure>
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/logo.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#3359f(), name: "assets/images/logo.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 1 of 1363 libraries in 356ms (compile: 20 ms, reload: 128 ms, reassemble: 177 ms).
D/EGL_emulation( 6231): app_time_stats: avg=1439.65ms min=27.34ms max=2851.96ms count=2

════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
Unable to load asset: assets/images/logo.png.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

this is the pubspec.yaml file::
assets:
- lib/assets/images/
- lib/assets/images/logo.png

Comment: did you add in pub.yaml file also?

Comment: Going forward: please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the element in the view should have had the following path:

```
       Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, right: 80),
              child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/logo.png'),
            ),
```

I missed the "lib/" part

Answer (score 2):

in your `pubspec.yaml` file , you must add the image as assets

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/logo.png
```

then you need to re-run your flutter app, to load the image.
do not only reload, your assets will not loaded.

Comment: no luck but thank you for the help!

this is the pubspec.yaml file::
  assets:
    - lib/assets/images/
    - lib/assets/images/logo.png 


this is how I am calling the file from the screen:

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, right: 80),
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
            ),